# How can I remove the left panel at Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion

This **left panel** narrows the **width**. I don't use it, and is a great waste of space:

[image]

How can I **remove** it, and left the same (and more practical) structure that StackExchange sites had a few moths ago?

Comment: I agree. I don't have an answer for you, but an alternative. If you zoom in slightly, the right portion of the screen is removed.

Answer (score 6):

Go to [Edit Profile & Settings](https://superuser.com/users/preferences) and select the "Hide left navigation" option.